# What is difference b/w group.id, application.id and client.id in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to kafka, So I am just clearing my kafka concepts.

I have created a simple streaming application which is streaming data from a single topic which has two partitions. I have two instances of this application (I am saying this on the basis of same application.id in both the projects). When I started third instance of the application, I got the error. From this, I understood that application.id in kafka is being treated as consumer group id where single consumer can read from single partition of a topic and 3rd consumer does not get any, so it failed to get store against the topic.

I have also tried another scenario where I changed application.id in one of the my applications. So by doing this, third instance of the application also started working fine. So it confirmed my hypothesis that application.id is being treated as consumer group id.

But I have also noticed that group.id, client.id also exists there which is confusing me. What is purpose of  using group.id, client.id in our projects, what are these properties and how they work. I have set up same group id for all three applications.

Comment: How about checking Kafka Reference? https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#application-id

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short:

- `client.id` (for [producer](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) and for [consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)) sets the name of an individual Kafka producer or consumer client.
- [`group.id`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) sets the name of the Kafka [consumer *group*](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) that an individual Kafka consumer client belongs to.
- [`application.id`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#application-id) is a setting only used by Kafka Streams to name an application, i.e., an application that uses the Kafka Streams library (which can be run on one or more app instances). Behind the scenes, the `application.id` is also used to generate `group.id` and `client.id`s. See the [application.id](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#application-id) documentation for further information.

Comment: if application.id is also used to set group.id, then why is it necessary to define group.id for the application separately and how it is being treated differently from application.id?

Comment: When you configure your Kafka Streams application, you only set `application.id`.  Kafka Streams will automatically configure `group.id` and `client.id`s as needed.

Comment: My pleasure. To your other question: I don't have an answer off the top of my head. I'd suggest to create a separate SO question for that.

Comment: The description of the third bullet point is partially incorrect. Kafka Streams uses the application.id as the prefix for the client.id. NOT as the client.id. If you do not provide a client.id then the client.id of the internal clients will be initialized with <application.id>-<random-UUID>. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

Comment: Ah, I should clarify the answer. Note that I didn't say the `application.id` is used as the `client.id`—the old answer said "it is also used to set the `group.id` and `client.id`s" (the "set" was unclear). Kafka Streams does use the `application.id` as a prefix for `client.id` (see docs), but please be aware there is NO contract that KStreams will specifically use `<application.id>-<random-UUID>` (as in your comment). This is an implementation detail and *may* change between Kafka versions. I'll clarify my answer.